# Coldfusion 11 CFIDE wont serve .cfm files after update

Tags: centos6, apache2, coldfusion

I've just updated a CF server to apply the latest hotfixes, via the CF administrator, restarted the server, all the sites back up, lovely.

But now I can't get into the CFIDE folder.

It's locked by IP to my location, I checked the `neo-security.xml` file and that had been reset to `10.*.*.*` so I deleted the IP, restarted CF again - I seem to remember doing this opens the restriction up so I can re-add the IP inside the administrator

Sites all came back up again, lovely, still no access to the CFIDE folder, sad times.

In my apache conf directly, in the `mod_jk.conf` file I have this line commented out so that CFIDE is not accessible from all the sites we host:

`#Alias /CFIDE "/PATH/TO/DEFAULT/SITE/CFIDE"`

In my default site I've got a symlink set up to point /CFIDE to the `CFROOT/cfusion/wwwroot/cfide` directory and I've got an apache conf file set to only allow access to the CFIDE folder from my IP

So it's all tied down by IP and CFIDE can only be reached using a specific URL which is only set up in local hosts files.

This was all working fine, until I applied the CF updates.

If I visit `example.com/CFIDE` I get a 403, which is fine.

If I visit `example.com/CFIDE/administrator` I get a 404, which is not-fine, it should be serving the index.cfm file.

If I visit `example.com/CFIDE/administrator/index.cfm` I get a 404, same as above. I get the same if I put in paths to other CFM files.

If I visit `example.com/CFIDE/administrator/index.html` after creating a simple Hello World file, that serves without a problem.

So it seems that updating to the latest CF hotfix has stopped `.cfm` files from being rendered when I try to access them in the browser.

Anyone got any ideas where I can go from here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I managed to get this sorted, more details can be found on the Adobe forums:
https://forums.adobe.com/thread/2403877

But I'd basically moved my CFIDE (for some reason, I think I was trying to create an alias for it) so most of the CFIDE was in one place, but the pages after the update were in another.

So I had my CFIDE split across 2 locations. I merged them back together and switched to using the built in web server just to serve the CFIDE.

The 404 errors I was getting were from nested includes, not the top level index.cfm/test.cfm pages I was trying to view.